# Which one is true while making kontrol with php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === 0)
```

or

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == 0)
```

---

Should I use `==` or `===` here?

Where can I use `===`?

Comment: Well, we don't know what `filter_input` is/does, so...

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, what do you mean? There is [documentation](http://www.php.net/filter_input) for filter_input().

Comment: @binaryLV: Ooh, that's new. Sorry.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, new? [PHP 5.2.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.0), year 2006 :)

Comment: @binaryLV: Compared to, say, 2005 that's new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP double equals matches only VALUE

```
if (2 == "2") this returns TRUE
```

Triple equals matches VALUE AND TYPE

```
if (2 === "2") this returns FALSE
```

Comment: Be careful with `==`... `('0' == false) == ('00' == false)` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`===` is used to make a strict comparison, that is, compare if the values are equal and of the same type.

Look at @Ergec's answer for an example.

---

In your case you should do just:

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false)
```

or simply

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

because `filter_input()` returns:

> Value of the requested variable on success, FALSE if the filter fails,
>   or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set. If the flag
>   FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is used, it returns FALSE if the variable is
>   not set and NULL if the filter fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `!== FALSE` in that case.

filter_input will either return the filtered variable or `FALSE`.

`===` checks if both sides are equal and of the same type.

`!==` checks if both sides are **not** equal and of the same type.

Comment: Caution: if `!== FALSE` is used, the filter will pass if the variable is not set.

Comment: About "*`!==` checks if both sides are **not** equal and of the same type.*" phrase - it should be written as "*`!==` checks if both sides are **not** equal **or** of the same type.*"

Comment: @binaryLV it's correct the way I wrote it.